# how to get value of download button into my django view?

Tags: python, django

I have a download button in my HTML that has a `href` to a path on my system for the corresponding file. How can I load that path into my view when at user clicks download? Also this value is unique for each download button.

If there's any other way that I can do this without exposing my system path in the `href` I would much prefer to know that. Thanks in advance.
 [image]

Right now I have some HTML that looks like this. How do I grab the info from `item.OutputPath` into my view when clicked?

```
 <div class="dashboard-2">   

      <div class="tasks-finished"> 

        <h1>Finished tasks</h1>   

      </div>  

      <div class="tasks-list">   

      <table>  

        <tr> 

            <th>Name</th>  

            <th>Task ID</th> 

            <th>Status</th>   

        </tr>   

        {% for item in query_finished %}  

        <tr>  

            <td>{{ item.TaskNavn }}</td>  

            <td>{{ item.TaskID }}</td>  

            <td><a href="{{ item.OutputPath }}">Download</a>        </tr> 

        {% endfor %}  

    </table> 

  </div> 

    </div>
```

Additonal info:

I need this value because i'm trying to save it as a variable to serve protected files using Nginx.

Comment: Why don't you just make the view to serve that file?

Comment: @seuling You're right that I should do that. Problem is I didn't know how or if it was possible before I asked this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exposing the system path is a bad idea in itself, but using it as an input parameter would be a huge security risk.

It is better to pass the id of your item to your download view. Something like this:

```
# template
<td><a href="{% url 'item-download' pk=item.pk %}">Download</a></tr> 

# urls.py
path('download/<int:pk>/', views.download_item, name='item-download'),

# views.py
def download_item(request, pk):
    # Make sure to perform any required checks, e.g. item.owner=request.user
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, pk=pk)
    output_path = item.OutputPath
    ...
```

Comment: You're definitely right in I should be doing something like this. Thank you very much. Care to answer one more question? I'm pretty new to coding so pardon my stupid questions. When running your code im receiving this exception `name 'Item' is not defined`

Comment: My code won‘t work as is, it is just supposed to point you in the right direction. Replace `Item` with your actual model class. Also make sure to add `from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404`

Comment: Thank you. I knew I had to replace it with something of my own but not sure what. Also I did import the 404. Thank you very much for the help! Have a nice day.